# NSURL Request not working

Tags: iphone, uiwebview, ios6, nsurl

I am building an app that would run a website through my app. Basically the webView. I had no problems so far since the last xCode update. It basically runs with no errors but it does not work on iOs 6 simulator or device.

.h fle:

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController{
    IBOutlet UIWebView *nView;
}
```

.m file:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSURL * myURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"];

                     NSURLRequest *myRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:myURL];

                     [nView loadRequest:myRequest];


}
```

If anyone can help I would be grateful. Thank you

Comment: "it does not work" - Please be more specific.

Comment: I should have said it crashes when I run it but I somehow got it fixed now. although now I have another issue. Can you help? If yes, see the answer I posted below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get it working!

.h file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIWebView *myWebView;

@end
```

.m file:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSURL *url =[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"];
    NSURL*request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [[self myWebView]loadRequest:request];
}
```

I included a property on h file and with some research I got the .m file working too. Although I got an issue saying:

> Incompatible pointer types sending 'NSURL *__strong' to parameter of
>   type 'NSURLRequest *'

Can anybody help to get rid of this issue as well please?

Comment: You should have made this a separate question. Regardless, you declare NSURL*request when it should be NSURLRequest *request.